# Getting records based on WHERE AND LIKE Logical Operators in SQL

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm having the table `restaurant` here, in which I have restaurant records.

Table schema

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cuisine` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `street_no` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_name` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `place_id` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `address` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
  `latitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Here, I'm trying to fetch the restaurant based upon these columns
**`city`**, **`address`**, **`status`**

Here if **`status=0`** that means restaurant is in **pending** state
and if **`status=1`** that means restaurant is in **Approved** state

**My Approach:**

```
 /**
 * GET RESTAURANT USING CITY OR ADDRESS
 *
 */
public function get_restaurant_by_city($city, $address="", $page_per_row, $pagenum)
{
    
    $this->db->where('status', 1)->like('cit', $city, 'both')->or_like('address', $address, 'both'); //both = %query%, before = %query, after = query%

   if (isset($pagenum) && $pagenum !== 0) {
     $pagenum  = ($pagenum - 1) * $page_per_row;
   }else { 
       if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
         $pagenum  = ($pagenum + 1) * $page_per_row;
       }else {
        $pagenum  = 0;
       }
   }

    $find  = $this->db->get($this->table, $page_per_row , $pagenum);
    return $find->result();
}
```

**Problem:** After applying `$this->db->where('status', 1)` I still getting the records which have `status=0`. It would be great if someone guides me a bit on how to write SQL queries in a perfect way to get the desired result.

**Demo data for use:**

`city` **Terrace**

`address` **4332 Lakelse Ave, Terrace, BC V8G 1N8, Canada**

Comment: use Query grouping

Comment: can you explain more about where you pointing?

Comment: CI2 or CI3? which CI version?

Comment: I guess CI v3.1

Comment: Refer https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=group_start#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @Devsi Odedra

Here is the solution to my problem.

```
 $this->db->group_start()   
            ->like('city', $city, 'both')
            ->or_like('address', $address, 'both')//both = %query%, before = %query, after = query%
            ->group_end()
            ->where('status', 1);
```